# Changing Geotagged Image file name into a Specific Polygon Attribute

Tags: qgis

I took a photo in the somewhere and took it into my computers. Then, added polygon data with each ID named on it (Brown land below ↓). And added Geo-Tagged JPG image with using [Import geotagged images] command. (orange dot ↓). Next thing I should do is change JPG File name as 8-digit numbers like shown on polygons.

We are plan to take millions of photo just tomorrow and no hope to find a way to change file names.

Simply, I could change every file name by myself, but I'm not sure if I could make it until this project end.

[image]